# Caused by java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "∞"

Tags: java, exception, floating-point

I am looking into Fabric Crashlytics to see crashes that my app has, and found this one:

> Caused by java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "∞"
>          at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>          at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:164)
>          at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:323)
>          at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306)

**Code**

```
public static Float parseFloat(String value) {
    return Float.parseFloat(value.replace(",", "."));
}
```

Please help me understand it.

Comment: Apparently you're asking it to parse the infinity symbol, which it can't handle. If you need to handle that, you could just check for that special case.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, do you know how is that even possible? because the user can only type like 5 caracteres (numbers)

Comment: They may have literally typed the infinity symbol, and whatever you're using to verify that numbers are being entered could consider that symbol a number and let it through.

Answer (score 0):

That's most likely a Float overflow.

If the Float is bigger than it can handle it returns infinity (this also happens dividing by 0). You should add a condition to check if the number is between -Float.MAX_VALUE and Float.MAX_VALUE (Float range goes from 1.40239846 x 10^-45 to 3.40282347 x 10^38)

Comment: I don't think an overflow would cause an infinity symbol to be produced, unless formatting was applied to it before attempting to parse it.